# Ubuntu 13.10 Unity doesn't load after upgrade

Tags: unity, upgrade, compiz

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 only to find that Unity won't load (login freezes, after doing ctrl+alt+F1, logging in and then doing startx, I get a blank desktop and the mouse pointer, and nothing else). I can right click, but the only operations that work are "create new file" and "create new folder". For example, "change desktop background" doesn't work. Also, after doing a few right clicks and choosing "change desktop background", I get a warning message box: "compiz closed unexpectedly."

Guest login works fine.

Tried creating a new user, but I experience the same thing with the new user.

Tried removing all configuration files from my home directory... same thing.

Doing dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ gives an error "error spawning command line..."

Doing unity --reset also gives errors.

Tried uninstalling unity (and compiz) and reinstalling, but that doesn't help. Tried reconfiguring lightdm, didn't help.

I don't have any proprietary drivers installed.

Once again, the funny thing is that the guest session works fine.

Comment: See the **second answer** in [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: @user68186: Well, this would only try to reset things through dconf (it seems the command is only a wrapper for a bunch of dconf reset commands). But as I said in my post, dconf is misbehaving. When I run what you suggested, I get a whole host of errors: "failed to commit changes to dconf: error spawning command line..."

Comment: Seems to be a problem with Cinnamon see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360772/unity-isnt-starting-on-13-10-with-cinnamon-2-0-installed

Comment: Assuming you have Cinnamon installed. I don't.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thing, and i press CRTL-Alt-T, to have a terminal. after that i enter ccsm to have compiz configurator. To the left, under all categories, i selected Preferences,and on the new screen i selected unity profil. Wait a few seconds and normally the launcher appers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll leave the question open for now, as I can't confirm this since I just went ahead and did a fresh install.

Comment: Fixed this issue for me on Ubuntu 13.10. I started **ccsm**, clicked **reset to defaults** in the **Preferences tab** and experienced no more crashes ever since.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that using ccsm solved my issue. I had some keybinding conflicts after the upgrade from 13.04-13.10 and as a result the "Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin" box was unchecked.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe a comment below Marc-Andre's answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi, that solved my problem with unity (i could login but no unity functionality was available).

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. During install my mouse and keyboard didn't respond anymore so I had to reboot the hard way halfway during installation.
After booting I could log in but only got a mouse pointer on a black screen.
My solution: Ctrl+Alt+F2, login, sudo dpkg --configure -a
I first tried sudo apt-get dist-upgrade but the prompt said I needed to give that command.
It then configured lots and lots of software. 
I rebooted the system and all seemed fine.