# 13.10 cannot login to Ubuntu default desktop environment - must use GNOME Flashback or Cinnamon

Tags: unity, 13.10, login, login-screen, desktop-environments

On boot at the password prompt - after I enter my password I get some error popup which disappears too fast to see then it reverts back to same password login Greeter screen.  Same screen has icons where I can choose :

```
Select desktop environment

Cinnamon
GNOME Flashback
Ubuntu
```

I really want to login to the normal ubuntu 13.10 Unity using above Ubuntu, however I can successfully login using either : Cinnamon or GNOME.  Suggestions ?  I have researched around and no help after removing file ~/.Xauthority  Also I see this :

```
cat .xsession-errors 
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
```

Comment: still researching ... appears to be related to Cinnamon install

Comment: I got the same error and found the solution on another post - http://askubuntu.com/questions/360772/unity-isnt-starting-on-13-10-with-cinnamon-2-0-installed

Answer (score 0):

Solution :  do NOT install Cinnamon 2 if you are using Unity - good news : all is well after purging everything mentioning cinnamon