# Cinnamon broke Unity and KDE on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, kde, cinnamon

Something after installing Cinnamon has screwed up my ability to use Unity and KDE on Ubuntu 13.10. When I try to log in to either I get an error that dbus could not start. Any ideas what has happened?  When I try to log in to KDE I get: "Could not start D-Bus. Can you call qbus?"

Comment: Similar or the same as this Q? http://askubuntu.com/questions/360772/unity-isnt-starting-on-13-10-with-cinnamon-2-0-installed?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Cinnamon from start up:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/upstart/sessions/cinnamon-se*
```

More info: http://itsfoss.com/quickly-fix-broken-unity-installing-cinnamon-20-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: This did not work... still the same borked system as before...

Answer (score -1):

try installing qdbus

```
sudo apt-get install qdbus
```