# Help! I can't login after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, login

After years of not upgrading to 14.04 I finally did it tonight. Everything went well until I tried logging in. When I try logging in using my usual username and password with the "Ubuntu (Default)" desktop environment I get an error saying (which I assume is Unity, right?):

"Could not acquire name on session bus" (or something like that)

When I "X" that it returns me to the login screen. Same thing when I try logging in as a guest.

I CAN log in using my username and password when I choose the "GNOME" and "GNOME Flashback (Compiz)" environments.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sometimes when I try to log in I can enter and there is a box saying:

"Could not acquire name on session bus"

If I ignore it, it seems I can do anything I want. But as soon as I "X" it it logs me out.

Usually, though, after entering my password the screen goes blacks with random letter (too quick for me to read) and returns me to the log in page.

Answer (score 0):

From command line

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Comment: I tried that several times and that alone didn't fix it.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it fixed it (even though I'm not really sure exactly what I did--especially since I didn't have Cinnamon installed)

[Unity isn't starting on 13.10 (with Cinnamon 2.0 installed)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360772/unity-isnt-starting-on-13-10-with-cinnamon-2-0-installed/360878#360878)